# show text just in the div and remove other part which is out of div

Tags: html, css

I want to show a text with anitmation and that move from right to left but the problem is text outside the div is visible and I want to hide text oute the div.

I make animation part but I coudn't make text unvisible out of the div element. I also set `over-flow:hidden` but that doesn't work.

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #f325;
}


.text{
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    animation: rightThenLeft 3s linear infinite;
}



@keyframes rightThenLeft {
    0%   {left: 0%;}
    100%  {left: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="text"> There is my text </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a minimal HTML to reproduce the issue. Read [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, no need for a negative `z-index` for the `p` tag.

Then you need to position it relative to its parent if you want to move only inside your div container.

Here's the solution:

```css
.text-h6{
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    animation: rightThenLeft 2s linear infinite;
    /* z-index:-1; */
  
}

.container-div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background:lightblue;
  position:relative;
    
}

@keyframes rightThenLeft {
    0%   {left: 0%;}
    100%  {left: 50%;}
}
```

```html
<div class='container-div'>
  <p class='text-h6'>This is the text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you problem solved by changing position to relative.